# Add a Delete Button in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imagebutton

I am trying to add a delete button which is supposed to delete an item in a database based on the position it has in the `RecyclerView`. I am struggling with this. Here is my layout file for the `RecyclerView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_list_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_list_name" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/layout_list_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:contentDescription="Delete"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_layout_delete_layout_item" />
```

This is where I declare the `onItemClick` for the `ImageButton` which is the delete button:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Delete hit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This is my `RecyclerView` listener class:

```
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public ListsDatabaseItemListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    onItemClickListener = listener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

    if (view != null && onItemClickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view));

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

And finally, here is my adapter class:

```
List<ListsDatabaseList> list;

public ListsDatabaseListAdapter(List<ListsDatabaseList> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public ListsDatabaseListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list, parent, false);
    ListsDatabaseListHolder holder = new ListsDatabaseListHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListsDatabaseListHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class ListsDatabaseListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView date;
    ImageButton delete;

    public ListsDatabaseListHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_name);
        this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_date);
        this.delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_delete);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: It is great that you provided this code, and all, but what is your question?

Comment: instead of adding the delete listener in activity, you can do this inside the onBindViewHolder in you Recycler Adapter.

Comment: I did ask my question at the very top but obviously didn't make myself too clear.

Comment: I was trying to add an onClickListener to my ImageButton in the RecyclerView.

Comment: post your error log and full Activity where you set the adapter to recyclerview

Comment: Check the comments with the answer provided below. My errors are all down there.

Comment: do you have any special events for touch? why gestures are used ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the `ImageButton` click listener in your `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListsDatabaseListHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ListsDatabaseList theRemovedItem = list.get(position);
              // remove your item from data base
              list.remove(position);  // remove the item from list
              notifyItemRemoved(position); // notify the adapter about the removed item
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to comment the onInterceptTouchEvent of your RecyclerView, i think it consumes the event.

Comment: I tried that. It only causes my app to crash. Is there any other method?

Comment: The error is when I comment out the onInterceptTouchEvent, it has a return type of a boolean. I need to keep return false; in that event handler or my app won't compile. When I do that, this error:     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I got this onInterceptEventhandler from a tutorial. I'm not to sure why it's there but if it is not required and will resolve the problem, then by all means tell me a way I can get rid of it so it doesn't interfere with my delete imagebutton.

Comment: Just remove the listener, and onInterceptTouchEvent() method (or make it always return false). Maybe in the tutorial he implemented this method to detect swipe events or sthg else.

Comment: Thankyou Rami! My app works now. I will figure out the sqlite database part myself now.

Comment: Hi , after **notifyItemRemoved(position),**
you must call also 
**notifyItemRangeChanged(position,getItemCount());**